# Adding Google Maps V3 User input through a searchbox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So, I found some instructions around and a few questions that seemed to answer this question, but none really worked for me or were very incomplete. I'm seeking a way to display the traditional google maps interaction of search and a pin is displayed on the map at the location. This marker, then, should be a blank option to include the data a user wants and the location saved to my database. I tried this sample by [Google Dev](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3) and it worked for a custom click on the map, but the integration with a simple [auto-complete search](http://gerger.co/blog/2011/02/17/google-maps-api-v3-location-search-with-jquery-autocomplete-plugin/) or even the [google's own autocomplete search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=pt#places_autocomplete) didn't quite worked.
I was wondering if there is a plugin or a technique (or a tutorial) that would suit this case (that I previously thought would be a simple matter as it is the traditional search on google maps). Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle. What went wrong?

Comment: thanks for the comment, @alkis!The instructions on the google api pages work for one of the requirements, but not the two together. I managed to get a (not as good as I wished) autocomplete feature and in another page I got the custom markers addition feature to save on the db. But when I put them together they end up braking. I couldn't search for a place and get the coordinates to put the pin on and also save on my db. I'll try to make a jsfiddle, but this week I'm a bit busy! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can show you how I did this page http://www.a-zhotels.net/register, you could easily combine all the fields into one autocomplete address field. However, this should give you an idea.

First, create a function:

```
function getMapByGeoLocation() {
    //build the address using many fields.
    var postcode = $("#HotelPostcode").val();
    var address = $("#HotelAddress").val();
    var town = $("#HotelTown").val();
    var city = $("#HotelCity").val();
    var country = $("#HotelCountryId > option:selected").text();

    var fulladdress = address + ', ' + town + ', ' + postcode + ', ' + city + ', ' + country;

    geocoder.geocode(
    {
        'address': fulladdress
    },
    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
            console.log(location);
            //map and marker should be previously created
            map.setCenter(location);
            map.setZoom(14);
            marker.setPosition(location);

            //These 2 hidden inputs will be posted to the server
            $("#HotelLatitude").val(location.Ya);
            $("#HotelLongitude").val(location.Za);

        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

This function is then called when the textbox and dropdowns change:

```
$("#HotelTown, #HotelAddress, #HotelPostcode").change(getMapByGeoLocation);
```

See below the function that creates the map:

```
var map;
var marker;
var geocoder;

function createMap() {
    if (map) { //Map already exists
        return;
    }
    if (!$('#mapCanvas').is(':visible')) {
        return;
    }
    var mapCanvas = $("#mapCanvas")[0];

    var averageLatitude = $("#HotelLatitude").val();
    var averageLongitude = $("#HotelLongitude").val();

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, {
        streetViewControl: true,
        zoom: 13,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(averageLatitude, averageLongitude)
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(averageLatitude, averageLongitude),
        draggable: true,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
        var position = marker.getPosition();
        map.panTo(position);
        $("#HotelLatitude").val(position.lat());
        $("#HotelLongitude").val(position.lng());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", function () {
        var position = map.getCenter();
        marker.setPosition(position);
        $("#HotelLatitude").val(position.lat());
        $("#HotelLongitude").val(position.lng());
    });
}

createMap();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for.
If you are looking for autocomplete field that adds a marker to the map after the user entered some string and opens an infowindow with a form on the map, is may be something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/XG9Qj/2/
It is important to notice, that this example only places a marker on the map if the user selected one of the suggestions from the autocomplete. To allow him to enter an arbitrary string you have to watch the input for RETURN and use the google maps geocoder on your own([1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pt#Geocoder)).

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode(...)
```